# Some of beacons are not read with locked iPhone screen

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I have written an application for iOS that reads beacons in background.
To keep the application active in background I am using "Audio and AirPlay" background mode. 
I am using CoreLocation API for ranging beacons.

All of my beacons are based on [MS47SF1](http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/538/8686.MS47SF1-Datasheet.pdf) module basis of [CC2541 chip](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjABahUKEwia97C7qvHGAhUKECwKHaC6B5o&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Fcc2541.pdf&ei=e-iwVdrNNYqgsAGg9Z7QCQ&usg=AFQjCNHKb3FnDH8Gcz-jbqztKbAuL4h9Dg&sig2=p-waw-Eee4bZh12I6OMtiQ&bvm=bv.98476267,d.bGg)

The problem is: some of the beacons stop ranging when screen locks. 
But other part of the beacons work well. However they all are similar.

Does anybody know how to fix it? 
I could not find any options in data sheet for CC2541 chip which could be related to this.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "some of the beacons stop ranging when screen locks. But other part of beacons work well. However they all are similar."  Are you saying that only some of the beacons show up in the ranging callback when the app is in the background but others do not?  If this is what you are saying, is there any difference between the ones that show up and the ones that do not?  Are the ones that show up consistent?

Comment: I have 50 beacons of the same manufacturer and model, they all are exactly the same, but only 3 of them are being read in background, others - not. These 3 beacons work really stable for a long period of time, longer than 1 week(I tested)

Comment: I have never seen anything like this before, and I have done lots of testing with ranging various beacon types in the background on iOS.  It would be helpful if you posted your code that does the ranging in both the foreground and background.  Perhaps there is something else that is making the difference.

Comment: I will upload my prototype project to some storage and send you a link. 
Are you using region monitoring or ranging for background beacon reading? How long your application work in background. Could you please post your code?

Comment: I have received response from BLE Devices manufacturer:
**Current MS52 beacon modules are not getting ready by an iPhone when it is locked.
If you require a MS52 beacon modules are read when an iPhone is locked, we can provide you the update firmware to reach it. Please advise.**